# if condition on adb logcat doesn't work

Tags: android, bash, shell, adb

I am trying the following code to get if condition on adb logcat:-

Search for the Exception or ANR (Activity Not Responding) on com.testapp.demo package If any Exception or ANR is found it will save the logs into the destination folder

```
if adb logcat | grep 'Exception*'
then
    adb logcat -d > $SILENT_EXCEPTION_FILE
fi
```

but I am not able to save it. Somehow this command does not work.

Answer (score 1):

`adb logcat` outputs the logs as they arrive and never exits, so `adb logcat | grep` never exits either. `adb logcat -d` should be used if you want to read the current logs.

Comment: improve your answer by giving a script solution

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the following:

```
adb logcat | grep --line-buffered 'Exception*' > $SILENT_EXCEPTION_FILE
```

Comment: but it creates a file even when no exception found...i want to create a file only when an exception is found.